# Provide Parameters to node when running ng build

Tags: angular

I have an angular 4 application which has a package.json that contains the following snippet:

```
"build": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --prod"
```

When I try to build my angular application, it dies with the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

When I google for this error, I find that the solution is to provide the `--max-old-space-size=4096` parameter when calling node. The problem is that my code does not call node - it calls ng. I looked through the [ng build options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and I did not find any obvious way to pass parameters to node.

How do I pass a parameter to node when I'm only calling ng?

Comment: did you try removing `./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/` and having just `ng build --aot --prod` as you script?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan - Thanks for the idea. I just went and tried it, but it didn't work. I got the same error message with standard ng build (without the node_modules).

Comment: Hmm, error may be some where else my be in your code somewhere, i would suggest try to create a very basic application using "ng new" and then add your code.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Were you able to answer your question?